# QM homework: I need to find result of this gaussian distribution integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, probability

This is a part of problem 1.3 from Griffiths's *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, 3rd Edition:

> Consider the gaussian distribution: $\rho (x) = Ae^{-\lambda
>  (x-a)^{2}}$
>
> Find $\left \langle x \right \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\rho
>  (x) \ dx$
>
> Where A, a, and $\lambda$ are positive real constants.
>
> (Look up any integrals you need)

I have scoured the web to find the result of this integral but have come up with nothing that includes the x term. I have normalized the distribution so I know what A is already, but beyond that I'm stumped. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. We have specific rules about homework-like questions, which you should read (see the help center). In short, you should show your own effort and prior research. Just saying "I can't figure this out" will most likely result in the question being closed. Also, this is a pure math question, and as such should probably be on the Math Stack Exchange. That said, it's almost surely a duplicate of another question there, so many try searching "Gaussian integral" there.

Comment: A simple variable transform takes it into an expression in my CRC Standard Math Tables from a gazillion years ago. And a little thought on what the expectation value of a shifted Gaussian _should_ be will lead in the right direction.

Comment: Can you integrate $x~e^{-x^2} ~dx$? The integrand looks a lot like the derivative of $e^{-x^2}$. The rest are just simple transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty easy integral, just make the change of variable $u = x - a$. As far as I can see, you should get a term where you can complete the differential, and another which is a Gaussian integral.